# wrapping legend text to fit the plot window

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to chart some data and I noticed that legends text are very long and not fitting the window.

```
+ opts(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = 'horizontal', size=0.1)  +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3), size=1)
```

Is there an option in ggplot to wrap the legend text to fit the window.

Comment: good question: a *reproducible* example might speed answers ...

Comment: Hard to post an answer without data. But AFAIK there's no option in `ggplot2`, but you can write a function to insert `\n`after some length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not as far as I know, so I have resorted to a workaround using `strwidth()`, which calculates the width of text in base graphics.

```
title <- "This is a really excessively wide title for a plot, especially since it probably won't fit"
```

Use `par("din")` to get the width of the device, and `strwidth()` to calculate the text size:

```
par("din")[1]
[1] 8.819444
strwidth(title, units="inches")
[1] 11.47222
```

Use it in a function and plot:

```
wrapTitle <- function(x, width=par("din")[1]){
  xx <- strwrap(x, width=0.8 * nchar(x) * width / strwidth(x, units="inches"))
  paste(xx, collapse="\n")
}

wrapTitle(title)
[1] "This is a really excessively wide title for a plot, especially since it\nprobably won't fit, meaning we somehow have to wrap it"
```

The plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + opts(title=wrapTitle(title))
```

[image]

---

If you want to save the plot to file, then you can replace `par("din")` with the actual saved plot dimensions.

Comment: I like your aproach, however as I understand, the OP wants to wrap the legend text not the title or legend title. Is there a way to know the dimensions of the grob where the legend text is?